# Dstore Filter: is there a way to compare properties?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dstore

Let's assume I have a store with different orders. The orders have a delivery address and an invoice address. The address itself has a city, street etc.:

```js
let data = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Anna', delivery: {city: "Amsterdam"}, invoice: {city: "Amsterdam"} },
        { id: 2, name: 'Anton', delivery: {city: "Amsterdam"}, invoice: {city: "Berlin"}}
];
```

I would like to filter all orders where the city of both the delivery address and the invoice address is the same.

I have tried that in a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gbwv2bde/3/, but I am not so happy with the results. Does anybody know a way to use a Filter for that task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will return items Anna and Julie

```
        var data = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Anna', delivery: { city: "Amsterdam" }, invoice: { city: "Amsterdam" } },
            { id: 2, name: 'Anton', delivery: { city: "Amsterdam" }, invoice: { city: "Berlin" } },
            { id: 3, name: 'John', delivery: { city: "Berlin" }, invoice: { city: "Paris" } },
            { id: 4, name: 'Julie', delivery: { city: "Paris" }, invoice: { city: "Paris" } }
        ];

        var myStore = new Memory({ data: data, idProperty: 'id' });
        var myResultsSet = myStore.filter(function (object) {
            return object.delivery.city === object.invoice.city;
        });

        myResultsSet.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log("item ", item.name);
        });
```

Basically you can create a your own functions to pass to filter(), which you can use to write your own comparison logic.

See here for more details
https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Collection.md

> filter(query)
>
> This filters the collection, returning a new subset collection. The
>   query can be an object, or a filter object, with the properties
>   defining the constraints on matching objects. Some stores, like server
>   or RQL stores, may accept string-based queries. Stores with in-memory
>   capabilities (like dstore/Memory) may accept a function for filtering
>   as well, but using the filter builder will ensure the greatest
>   cross-store compatibility.

**EDIT**: Example with more properties to compare.  Your function just needs to return a true or false (true if the object matches your comparison conditions)

```
        var data = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Anna', delivery: { city: "Amsterdam", price: 5 }, invoice: { city: "Amsterdam", price: 20 } },
            { id: 2, name: 'Anton', delivery: { city: "Amsterdam", price: 8 }, invoice: { city: "Berlin", price: 7 } },
            { id: 3, name: 'John', delivery: { city: "Berlin", price: 10 }, invoice: { city: "Paris", price: 20 } },
            { id: 4, name: 'Julie', delivery: { city: "Paris", price: 2 }, invoice: { city: "Paris", price: 3  } }
        ];

        //example for custom filtering with nested properties
        var myStore = new Memory({ data: data, idProperty: 'id' });
        var myResultsSet = myStore.filter(function (object) {
            if(object.delivery.city === object.invoice.city){
                if (object.delivery.price < 5 && object.invoice.price < 5)
                    return true;
            }else
                return false;
        });

        myResultsSet.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log("item ", item.name);
        });
```

Comment: Hi erotavlas, thanks for the quick answer! This works perfect for the described issue. Unfortunately, I have simplified my issue a bit too much... the query whether the cities are equal is embedded in a bigger filter, like "The cities match AND the price is LT x euro OR the cities do not match AND the price is GT y euro" - I know this is a strange example, but I do not want to post the real issue... Could your code be integrated in such a Filter?

Comment: @ikorni are you saying that you want to create a more complex filter based on multiple properties (not just city)?  In any case I updated my answer with another example that shows you can put whatever logic you want in the function.

Comment: I think I need to create another question to show what I mean, I will as soon as I find time